# Can't scrape HTML table using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data off a table on a web page using Python, BeautifulSoup, Requests, as well as Selenium to log into the site.
Here's the table I'm looking to get data for...

```html
<div class="sastrupp-class">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="key">Thing I dont want 1</td>
                    <td class="value money">$1.23</td>

                    <td class="key">Thing I dont want 2</td>
                    <td class="value">99,999,999</td>

                    <td class="key">Target</td>
                    <td class="money value">$1.23</td>

                    <td class="key">Thing I dont want 3</td>
                    <td class="money value">$1.23</td>

                    <td class="key">Thing I dont want 4</td>
                    <td class="value percentage">1.23%</td>

                    <td class="key">Thing I dont want 5</td>
                    <td class="money value">$1.23</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

I can find the "sastrupp-class" fine, but I don't know how to look through it and get to the part of the table I want.
I figured I could just look for the class that I'm searching for like this...

```
    output = soup.find('td', {'class':'key'})
    print(output)
```

but that doesn't return anything.

Important to note:

1. < td>s inside the table have the same class name as the one that I want. If I can't separate them out, I'm ok with that although I'd rather just return the one I want.

2.There are other < div>s with class="sastrupp-class" on the site.

3. I'm obviously a beginner at this so let me know if I can help you help me.
   Any help/pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: It work fine in my computer, is it the actual code? If you trying to get specific element base on it text, you can first 'find_all', then filter other element by their content.

Comment: https://www.itextpad.com/wFsEvS7eDb here is what i have try

Comment: maybe this part of table is generated by javascript so requests can't get it. dowload page to HTML file and open it in editor to check HTML tags.

Comment: @furas I believe that is it. I cannot see the table when I view the page source. When I inspect the elements, I can see comments saying each item is from a function called summary().

Comment: so now check all files used by page and find `summary()`. Or use `"Developer Tools"` in Chrome or `"Firebug"` in Firefox to see all data readed by browser from server - maybe you find your data in different file.

Comment: btw: it is easier when you add url of this page.

Answer (score -1):

1) First of, to get your 'Target' you need *find_all*, not *find*. Then, considering you know exactly in which position your target will be (in the example you gave it is index=2) the solution could be reached like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """(YOUR HTML)"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find('div', {'class': 'sastrupp-class'})
all_keys = table.find_all('td', {'class': 'key'})
my_key = all_keys[2]

print my_key.text  # prints 'Target'
```

2)

> There are other < div>s with class="sastrupp-class" on the site

Again, you need to select the one you need using *find_all* and then selecting the correct index.

Example HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="sastrupp-class"> Don't need this</div>
<div class="sastrupp-class"> Don't need this</div>
<div class="sastrupp-class"> Don't need this</div>
<div class="sastrupp-class"> Target</div>
</body>
```

To extract the target, you can just:

```
all_divs = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'sastrupp-class'})
target = all_divs[3]  # assuming you know exactly which index to look for
```